# Analytical expression of a CatBoost regression model in R

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, catboost

When adjusting a multiparametric regression model, an analytical expression that characterizes the fitted model (e.g., in a linear multiparametric regression, the equation is $\hat\beta= \hat\beta_o+\sum^{N}_{i=1} \hat\alpha_{i}\cdot x_i$) can be obtained. The parameters $\alpha_i$ are displayed when `summary()` function is called.

However, when a categorical boosting (CatBoost) regression model is adjusted, how can I obtain an expression that summarizes the model? I'm using R programming.